# magento bundle.js error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, prototype, magento

I just discovered on my site using magento 1.3.2.2 that on a bundled product, when adding different options the price does not change in internet explorer. It works fine in all other browsers however.

In internet explorer I get the error message.

```
Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 34
Char: 9
Code: 0
URI: /skin/frontend/my_new_interface/design2/js/bundle.js
```

So I checked out line 34 and found

```
parts = selection.id.split('-');
```

I verified that *selection.id* is a string. I'm not a javascript expert and I'm not familiar with prototype.

On a lark I decided to split up the line as:

```
var parts = selection.id;
parts = part.split('-');
```

Well that fixed the problem. Furthermore I went back and just reduced to:

```
var parts = selection.id.split('-');
```

Which still worked as well. I don't think this is a file I should be messing with though. I'm assuming this javascript class should work fine in ie without me having to change anything.

I'm hoping someone has an idea of why this might have fixed the problem or what I can do to find out what the real problem is. Do you see any problem with me leaving this fix the way it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very possible that you hit an ID in the other case that didn't exist, and therefore it was attempting to split an undefined variable. If the fix works for you, stick with it, but you may want to consider upgrading your Magento installation. The series is onto 1.4 now, and there are huge numbers of fixes in every release.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe